# Glass BeginEditFrame to edit children of a referenced DropLink field

Tags: glass-mapper

I am looking for some help in figuring out an appropriate approach to this setup.
I have a Sitecore tree that looks something like this:

- content

  - settings
  - home

    - potato

      - spud1
      - spud2

The `settings` node has a droplink field that points to the `potato` item.  I have a POCO model that roughly looks like this:

```
[SitecoreType( AutoMap=true, TemplateId="1234..." )]
public class ModelA {
   public virtual Guid Id { get; set;}
   public virtual String Name { get; set; }
   public virtual ModelB Potato { get; set; }
}

[SitecoreType( AutoMap=true, TemplateId="1235..." )]
public class ModelB {
   public virtual Guid Id { get; set;}
   public virtual IEnumerable<Spud> Children { get; set; }
}
```

While the general rendering behaviour of this setup seems fine, we're having some issues trying to get an edit frame where we can add a new `spud3` to the list of spuds.

The current setup has been centered around:

```
@using( BeginEditFrame( Model, "Title", m => m.Potato ) ) {}
```

but this isn't really doing what we want (haven't got *exactly* what it's not doing at hand as I'm posting on behalf of someone, but will update in 12hrs time with additional detail).

Assuming what we're trying to do is reasonable, can anyone spot the issue in the setup above?

We've also noticed a (probably known) bug where if the last 2 (supposedly optional) arguments of the `BeginEditFrame()` method are omitted a `NullReferenceException` is thrown from Sitecore's `WebControl::GetItem()`.
[Note please @MikeEdwards if you're reading this ;)]

Answer (score 1):

Can you change this to use datasources? If you did that then the rendering would point to `potato` as its datasource. You would add the `Insert` web edit button to your rendering's `Experience Editor Buttons` field.

If it isn't possible then try changing your edit frame code to pass in the insert button. You should create a custom folder under `/sitecore/content/Applications/WebEdit/Edit Frame Buttons` in core and duplicate the insert button into it (the insert button is located at `/sitecore/content/Applications/WebEdit/Edit Frame Buttons/Default/Insert`). Then you would pass in your datasource item and the button folder's id to the edit frame:

`@using(Html.BeginEditFrame(Model.Potato.Id, {Your_Custom_Button_Folder}) ) {}`

Comment: An interesting idea. Will investigate this further. I've since found out that the frame that comes up seems to target the DropLink field rather than its children, which makes sense I suppose, but isn't what we want.  I'm a little surprised custom code is needed for this; seems like something most people would want to do at some point. We use this pattern all the time.

Comment: You're not wrong with how it is set up. The rendering will use the current context item to determine what to target. This means if you populate the rendering's data source with the item `potato` then it should target the item you would expect. Otherwise you are stuck using an edit frame and passing it the id or path of the item you want to target.

Comment: You can have Glass target the children, if for example you render the `Children` in a foreach loop then you can `BeginEditFrame(child, "Title", c => c.SpudField)` as long as the `Spud` model has a `[SitecoreId]` set. This works for Edits, not sure about Inserts off top of my head... Looks like @Teeknow method would work though

Comment: @jammykam correct that does allow editing the current item but they need the parent item if they want to add items that will be siblings to those items